# Dates to categories

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have an Excel spreadsheet I'm preparing to migrate to Access and the date column has entries in multiple formats such as: 1963 to 1969, Aug. 1968 to Sept. 1968, 1972, Mar-73, 24-Jul, Oct. 2, 1980, Aug 29, 1980, July 1946, etc. and 'undated'. I'm pulling the column that will be the key (map number) and date column into a csv and writing back to a csv. 
I can strip out years that are 4 digit, but not ranges. And I'm stumped how to extract days and 2 digit years short of re-formatting by hand. My code isn't very elegant and probably not best practice:

```
import csv, xlwt, re

# create new Excel document and add sheet
# from tempfile import TemporaryFile
from xlwt import Workbook
book = Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

# populate first row with header
sheet1.write(0,0,"Year")
sheet1.write(0,1,"Map")
sheet1.write(0,2,"As Entered")

# count variable for populating sheet
rowCount=0

# open csv file and read
with open('C:\dateTestMSDOs.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:

        map = row[0]  # first row is map number
        dateRaw = row[1] # second row is raw date as entered

        # write undated and blank entries
        if dateRaw == 'undated':
            yearStr = '0000'
            rowCount +=1
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
            #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
            yearStr=''

        if dateRaw == '':
            yearStr = 'NoEntry'
            rowCount +=1
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
            #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
            yearStr=''

        # search and write instances of four consecutive digits
        try:
            year = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', dateRaw)
            yearStr= year.group()
            #print yearStr, map, dateRaw
            rowCount +=1
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
            #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
            yearStr=''

        # if none exist flag for cleaning spreadsheet and print
        except:
            #print 'Nope', map, dateRaw
            rowCount +=1
            yearStr='Format'
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
            #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
            yearStr=''
yearStr=''
dateRaw=''

book.save('D:\dateProperty.xls')
print "Done!"
```

I would like to write day and month to an additional column as well as pull the second 4 digit date of range entries.

Comment: Have you looked at formatting dates in [datetime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)?

Comment: [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) has powerful date parsing capabilities. I would take a look at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `dateutil` for this. I think you'd still need to deal with some of the more difficult formats in a different way though. See a sample implementation below:

**Code:**

```
import dateutil.parser as dateparser

date_list = ['1963 to 1969', 
             'Aug. 1968 to Sept. 1968', 
             'Mar-73', 
             '24-Jul', 
             'Oct. 2 1980', 
             'Aug 29, 1980', 
             'July 1946', 
             'undated']          

for d in date_list:
    if 'to' in d:
        a, b = d.split('to')
        # Get the higher number. Use min to get lower of two.
        print max(dateparser.parse(a.strip()).year, dateparser.parse(b.strip()).year)
    elif d == 'undated':
        print '0000'
    else:
        yr = dateparser.parse(d).year
        print yr
```

**Result:**

```
1969
1968
1973
2014
1980
1980
1946
0000
[Finished in 0.4s]
```

Only glaring issue I can see is that `24-Jul` returns a date of `2014` because the parser assumes the current day, month, or year in place of missing component, ie. `Mar-73` will become `1973-03-20` if today is the 20th of the month, etc.

Comment: Absolutely the best way I've seen to handle this, and better than my code. I wish I would have remembered your post when we changed focus to not make days and months a searchable parameter.

Comment: Admittedly, I would have used `pandas` instead, but without access to your data, this is the best I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you were going for or not but I just used a "simple" regex search and then traversed through the sets of groups that matched, applying the given function defined. If a match is found then the function that is called (found in the regex_groups variable) should return a dictionary with the following keys: `start_day, start_month, start_year, end_day, end_month, end_year`

Then you can do whatever you'd like with those values. Definitely not the cleanest solution but it works, as far as I can tell.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import re

# Crazy regex
regex_pattern = '(?:(\d{4}) to (\d{4}))|(?:(\w+)\. (\d{4}) to (\w+)\. (\d{4}))|(?:(\w+)-(\d{2}))|(?:(\d{2})-(\w+))|(?:(\w+)\. (\d+), (\d{4}))|(?:(\w+) (\d+), (\d{4}))|(?:(\w+) (\d{4}))|(?:(\d{4}))'

date_strings = [
  '1963 to 1969',
  'Aug. 1968 to Sept. 1968',
  '1972',
  'Mar-73',
  '24-Jul',
  'Oct. 2, 1980',
  'Aug 29, 1980',
  'July 1946',
]

# Here you set the group matching functions that will be called for a matching group
regex_groups = {
  (1,2):      lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': '', 'start_month': '', 'start_year': group_matches[0], 
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': group_matches[1]
  },
  (3,4,5,6):  lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': '', 'start_month': group_matches[0], 'start_year': group_matches[1], 
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': group_matches[2], 'end_year': group_matches[3]
  },
  (7,8):      lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': '', 'start_month': group_matches[0], 'start_year': group_matches[1], 
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': ''
  },
  (9,10):     lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': group_matches[1], 'start_month': '', 'start_year': group_matches[0],
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': ''
  },
  (11,12,13): lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': group_matches[1], 'start_month': group_matches[0], 'start_year': group_matches[2],
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': ''
  },
  (14,15,16): lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': group_matches[1], 'start_month': group_matches[0], 'start_year': group_matches[2],
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': ''
  },
  (17,18):    lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': '', 'start_month': group_matches[0], 'start_year': group_matches[1], 
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': ''
  },
  (19,):      lambda group_matches: {
    'start_day': '', 'start_month': '', 'start_year': group_matches[0], 
    'end_day': '', 'end_month': '', 'end_year': ''
  },
}

for ds in date_strings:
  matches = re.search(regex_pattern, ds)
  start_month = ''
  start_year = ''
  end_month = ''
  end_year = ''

  for regex_group, group_func in regex_groups.items():
    group_matches = [matches.group(sub_group_num) for sub_group_num in regex_group]
    if all(group_matches):
      match_data = group_func(group_matches)
      print
      print 'Matched:', ds
      print '%s to %s' % ('-'.join([match_data['start_day'], match_data['start_month'], match_data['start_year']]), '-'.join([match_data['end_day'], match_data['end_month'], match_data['end_year']]))

      # match_data is a dictionary with keys:
      #   * start_day
      #   * start_month
      #   * start_year
      #   * end_day
      #   * end_month
      #   * end_year
      # If a group doesn't contain one of those items, then it is set to a blank string
```

Outputs:

```
Matched: 1963 to 1969
--1963 to --1969

Matched: Aug. 1968 to Sept. 1968
-Aug-1968 to -Sept-1968

Matched: 1972
--1972 to --

Matched: Mar-73
-Mar-73 to --

Matched: 24-Jul
Jul--24 to --

Matched: Oct. 2, 1980
2-Oct-1980 to --

Matched: Aug 29, 1980
29-Aug-1980 to --

Matched: July 1946
-July-1946 to --
```

Comment: Thank you, Bryce. This is pretty much where I wanted to go before time ran short and the job parameters changed focus.  I'll preserve this code, though. I have a pile of nasty data to clean up in a few months, and in lieu of a more efficient approach this will adapt perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You could define all the possible cases of dates using regex, something like:

```
import re
s = ['1963 to 1969', 'Aug. 1968 to Sept. 1968',
     '1972', 'Mar-73', '03-Jun', '24-Jul', 'Oct. 2, 1980', 'Oct. 26, 1980',
     'Aug 29 1980', 'July 1946']


def get_year(date):
    mm = re.findall("\d{4}", date)
    if mm:
        return mm
    mm = re.search("\w+-(\d{2})", date)
    if mm:
        return [mm.group(1)]

def get_month(date):
    mm = re.findall("[A-Z][a-z]+", date)
    if mm:
        return mm

def get_day(date):
    d_expr = ["(\d|\d{2})\-[A-Z][a-z]+","[A-Z][a-z]+[\. ]+(\d|\d{2}),"]
    for expr in d_expr:
        mm = re.search(expr, date)
        if mm:
            return [mm.group(1)]

d = {}
m = {}
y = {}

for idx, date in enumerate(s):
    d[idx] = get_day(date)
    m[idx] = get_month(date)
    y[idx] = get_year(date)

print "Year Dict: ", y
print "Month Dict: ", m
print "Day Dict: ", d
```

As result you get dictionaries of days, month, and years. They could be used to populate the rows.

Output:

```
Year Dict:  {0: ['1963', '1969'], 1: ['1968', '1968'], 2: ['1972'], 3: ['73'], 4: None, 5: None, 6: ['1980'], 7: ['1980'], 8: ['1980'], 9: ['1946']}
Month Dict:  {0: None, 1: ['Aug', 'Sept'], 2: None, 3: ['Mar'], 4: ['Jun'], 5: ['Jul'], 6: ['Oct'], 7: ['Oct'], 8: ['Aug'], 9: ['July']}
Day Dict:  {0: None, 1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: ['03'], 5: ['24'], 6: ['2'], 7: ['26'], 8: None, 9: None}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions! I thought I would post my clumsy code that worked. The output .xls was imported into our database as a LU table and is working fine. Downside is that any spaces or extra characters break it, but the upside of the downside is that it enforces that the raw data entry conforms to an output of a single searchable year category in the database (which is what we had to settle on since we were dealing with ranges, days, months, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the innovative suggestions. After consideration we decided to remove day and month from what would be searchable in our database, since only a relatively small amount of our data had that level of detail. Here is the code I use to extract and generate the data I needed from a long and messy list.

```
import csv, xlwt, re
# create new Excel document and add sheet
from xlwt import Workbook
book = Workbook()
sheet1 = book.add_sheet('Sheet 1')

# populate first row with header
sheet1.write(0,0,"MapYear_(Parsed)")
sheet1.write(0,1,"Map_Number")
sheet1.write(0,2,"As_Entered")

# count variable for populating sheet
rowCount=0

# open csv file and read
yearStr = ''
with open('C:\mapsDateFix.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:

        map = row[0]  # first row is map number
        dateRaw = row[1] # second row is raw date as entered

        # write undated and blank entries
        if dateRaw == 'undated':
            yearStr = 'undated'
            rowCount +=1
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
            sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
            #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
            #yearStr=''

        if yearStr != 'undated':
            if dateRaw == '':
                yearStr = 'NoEntry'
                rowCount +=1
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
                #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
                #yearStr=''

        # search and write instances of four consecutive digits
        if yearStr != dateRaw:
            try:
                year = re.search(r'\d\d\d\d', dateRaw)
                yearStr= year.group()
                #print yearStr, map, dateRaw
                rowCount +=1
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
                #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
                yearStr=''

             # if none exist flag for cleaning spreadsheet and print
            except:
                #print 'Nope', map, dateRaw
                rowCount +=1
                yearStr='Format'
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 0, yearStr)
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 1, map)
                sheet1.write(rowCount, 2, dateRaw)
                #print rowCount, yearStr, map, dateRaw, '\n'
                yearStr=''
yearStr=''
dateRaw=''

book.save('D:\dateProperty.xls')
print "Done!"
```